# WPF TreeView styled like the Mac NSOutlineView

Tags: wpf, treeview

I'd like to style my TreeView like the Mac NSOutlineView.

http://s3.amazonaws.com/cocoacontrols_production/osx_screens/44/full.png?1299027729

The key features being:

1. TreeView full width highlighting of selected item
2. Background color
3. Different style for root header items

I believe I can track down 2 and 3, but can't find anything related to number 1.

Seems like I can't really do it, but I'll play around with Blend. Is there no code access to drawing? like here is a box replace the row drawing code? I made a prototype just now in wxPython using AGW's pure python HyperTreeList that looks the same, but unfortunately dragging and dropping has serious graphics/refresh issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle be appropriate ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle(v=vs.85).aspx

**A quick test under Blend brought the following :**

For a parent :

[image]

For a children :

[image]

Notice that it is uneven, it doesn't look good.

One might ask why not stretching it up to the left border ? I guess this is not possible (from what I've seen on Blend) unless you recreate most of the template of course.
Also this would certainly kill the hierarchical look there is between items if their selector left side would be aligned to the same horizontal value.

Now the other thing is that even though you'd do that (as you requested), the expander triangle would be lost in a mess of blue ... bad UX in my opinion.

In the end your control would look more like a ListBox than a TreeView.

Anyway, here's the procedure (I edited ItemContainerStyleTemplate of a TreeView)

[image]

(sorry didn't read well your last comment, in the end my result is pretty much like yours)

Where to do it in Blend :

[image]

Comment: I've tried working with this, but it only covers the item which is right of the expansion arrow until end of the string.

Comment: I've added a picture on where to do it in Blend. Also, note that if you're on VS2012 and working in a WPF project, only Blend + Sketchflow Preview will allow you to edit such project, not Blend for Visual Studio 2012. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/jj154135.aspx (it took me a while to figure why I couldn't edit WPF projects with the Blend delivered with VS2012 ... :-) Lastly, I'd say Blend is like bread for butter, you really need it when you start getting serious with WPF, unless you are fond of coding all the XAML by hand.

Comment: I want to upvote this some more. I just ran into several other SO questions with the same full row highlight question and all the answers are more difficult than they need to be if you just use blend.

Comment: The actual way to full row highlight is to name the grid in the item container and then set its background.

Comment: Beware, some controls are template parts.

Answer (score 0):

I have just pushed on [Mongoose](http://mongoose.codeplex.com/) repository a TreeViewItem Style that does what you need.

You can find it here : [StretchedTreeViewItemControlTemplate](http://mongoose.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/838b68ea535aaa05b1fd85d2652be01a9bfc422a#Mongoose/Mongoose.Windows/Themes/Generic/TreeViewItem.xaml)

Here is a sample code :

```
<TreeView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StretchedTreeViewItemControlTemplate}">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Item 1">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 1.1">
            <TreeViewItem.Style>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource StretchedTreeViewItemControlTemplate}" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
                </Style>
            </TreeViewItem.Style>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Item 2" Background="AntiqueWhite" />
</TreeView>
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoted for useful code to examine. Not sure I can use the TreeView as  I want without the full width row highlight left to right. It just looks odd to me in my use case.

Comment: Link is now dead.