# wpf TreeView - select row on click anywhere in row

Tags: wpf, treeview

The wpf TreeView only selects a row when the text if clicked on. I'd like to have the selection occur no matter where the click occurs in the row. Except perhaps on the expander I guess but would have to see.

Currently I stretch the text to the width of the treeview using the technique posted here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15813560/317033

However that leaves the empty space on the left of nested child nodes still unreactive.

Comment: Please show the code, including the styling code. Otherwise every possible answer here you be pure guessing.

Comment: No need to show code if you read the question.

Comment: I read your text but miss another question than "I'd like to have the selection occur no matter where the click occurs in the row." The answer to this is "Yes, you do." if I'm a bit sarcastic, or "Well then just change that". If there's nothing to work with, noone can help.

Comment: A treeview handles its own selection. You don't add code to make it select rows. This selection only occurs when you click on the text. As the question states I want the selection to occur no matter where in the row you click. There is no code to show you.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/672123/317033

Based on reviewing this answer I modified the ControlTemplate of the TreeViewItem replacing it with my own version which filled the width of the TreeView. It'd be nice if there was another way since this obviously is a major change.

Handling a click in the TreeView was my previous thought, but I couldn't find a way to get the item for that click if the click occurred to the right or left of the item.